# Default configuration for Eclipse plugin test

Tags: eclipse, junit, eclipse-plugin

I'm working on a project developing an Eclipse-based application. Running a JUnit plug-in test requires the run configuration for it to have a bunch of parameters set. This means that if I want to run a single test class or method, as far as I can tell I have to create a new configuration or edit one that I reuse. More annoyingly I can't use the convenience of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd>.

Is there a way to tell Eclipse that a bunch of parameters are the defaults for an implicitly created run configuration of a given type to use it when it's automagically creating one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a custom target platform (which you should use anyway), you can specify *Program arguments* and *VM arguments* on the *Environment* tab of the target platform editor.

[image: VM arguments section of the target platform editor]

They will be used as default values for PDE launch configurations.

Comment: I'll try this when I get home. We are using a target platform but I'm not the person that defined it, no idea why these parameters would be missing from it.

Comment: We are using a custom platform, but the Eclipse platform definition doesn't allow for setting the path to the application's config.ini, or to run the test on / off of the UI thread.

Comment: It should be possible to emulate config.ini settings through the _Program_ arguments. Why would you want to run tests on or off the UI thread?

Comment: These tests are "integration" tests, meaning they programatically create the plug-in UI and send simulated input events to it. As to why the config.ini settings are in config.ini, I've no idea, I'd have to ask my seniors. Going by precedent, it's probably "we didn't know this was possible / never figured something like it would be useful."

Comment: There is no special setting needed to run PDE tests on the UI thread. They are always run on the UI thread.